# Android Play store is complaining about not including debug symbols submitting an app bundle with flutter 3.0.0 which previously worked

Tags: flutter, android-ndk, google-play, publish, android-app-bundle

When saving a flutter 3.0.0 build bundle for a release on the play store, we get currently this error on the playstore..

**Playstore error: App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols**

But if we compare the bundle meta data we do see symbols.
**Note:** prior the flutter upgrade to 3.0.0 we did **not** see the error. What is the play store looking for in the new app budle?

PS. we did all the necessary updates on the gradle scripts for including debug symbols (NDK)

[image: bundle meta data]